# Get instance from selectbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, drop-down-menu

I've got select box with users in Rails. Is there any simple way, how to get selected instance from that selectbox?

**show.html.erb**:

```
<select id="user_select" name="user_select" class="input-medium">
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <option><%= user.username %></option>
   <% end %>
</select>
<!-- button to addfriend method like on next example -->
```

In this time, I've got something like this on this place:

```
<ul id="user_list" name="user_list">
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <li><%= user.username %></li>
      <%= link_to "Add", addfriend_project_path(@project, :user_id => user.id) %>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

And I need to get some user info from that selectbox for my method -> id will be the best.

Comment: with jQuery: `$('#user_select').val()`

Comment: But it returns only username which is written in that selectbox right?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this:

```
<select id="user_select" name="user_select" class="input-medium">
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <option><%= user.username %></option>
   <% end %>
</select>
```

Use the [`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag#54-select-tag-with-options-for-select-example) method coming from the FormHelper:

```
<%= select_tag :user_select, options_for_select(@users.map{|u| [u.username, u.id]}), class: 'input-medium' %>
```

And then, using jQuery to get the user_id select in the select box:

```
var user_id = $('#user_select').val();
# This will alert the selected user_id every time the select_box changes:
$('#user_select').change(function(event){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Is this the best way how to do it? That is not that elegant like I expected.

Comment: Yes it is the best way to do it @medy75: you need to use javascript on the client side to catch the event when the user changes the select_box (Ruby is on the server side).